# RequireJS and common config

Tags: javascript, requirejs, config

Is possible to have requirejs config at one place and reuse it in modules?

such as

main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "static/js", 
    paths: {
         "jquery": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js",    
     "jquery-ui": "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"
},
shim: {
     "jquery-ui": {
          deps: ["jquery"]
     }
}
});
```

and

public.js:

```
define(["main", "jquery", function(main, $) {
    // do some public stuff
});
```

client.js:

```
define(["main", "jquery", function(main, $) {
    // do some client stuff
});
```

And on my public part of web have

```
<script type="..." src="js/require.js" data-main="js/public.js"></script>
```

And on client part of web

```
<script type="..." src="js/require.js" data-main="js/client.js"></script>
```

And also I would like to have a module for each page. So for example to have a index module on public

```
<script ...>
    require('public/index');
</script>
```

and

public/index.js:

```
define(["jquery", "slideshow"], function($, s) {
    $( function() { s.init() } );
});
```

Is that possible with RequireJS?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: You forgot the closing brackets in your public.js and client.js code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit my answer as you make the question clearer.

In any page you include `require.js`, you should also include `main.js` to define your RequireJS config.

You can't do things like

```
define(["main", "jquery", function(main, $) {
    // do some public stuff
});
```

because ReuiqreJS load dependencies asynchronously. Although "main" is placed before "jquery", it's not guaranteed RequireJS will load them in that sequence.

So your public/index.html can be like:

```
<script type="..." src="js/require.js"></script>
<script type="..." src="js/main.js"></script>
<script ...>
    require('public/index');
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean like into page? Add another script? Something like <script src="require.js" data-main="main"></script> <script src="require.config.js"></script> ?

Comment: @Douglish Are you building single page application? If it is, you don't need to define main.js in your public.js or client.js. Instead, include <script src="main.js"></script> in your bootstrap file (e.g. index.html), so all your modules can see it as it's a single page application. If you are not building SPA, you may want to include that main.js or define it as you did everywhere.

Comment: I would like to achieve that I have one script for whole site, like the main.js, then a modules for public and client's part of website and also a script for each page, like index, registration etc. I was thinking about having index.js included in page like require('index') on index.html and it would require public which would require main.js but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Douglish So it looks like you are building multiple page application. You CAN'T define public.js with "main" and "jquey" as dependencies at the same time. You HAVE to include "main.js" first, and then define "jquery" as dependency for your module, because "juqey" relies on your config in "main.js", and RequireJS load dependencies asynchronously. In you case, RequireJS may ask for "jquery" first, and it can't find the right path.

Comment: That definitely helped and now it's clear to me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

`data-main` is a useful shortcut in the very simple case but I don't find it terribly useful beyond that, the solution is to dump it entirely.

Load your main explicitly on each page, then use the callback to load your view-specific scripts.

So you have in public.html:

```
<script src="/Scripts/require.js"></script>
<script>
require('main', function(){
  require('public');
})
</script>
```

and in client.html:

```
<script src="/Scripts/require.js"></script>
<script>
require('main', function(){
  require('client');
})
</script>
```

[I've written a blog post expounding on this idea here.](https://github.com/togakangaroo/Blog/blob/master/setting-up-requirejs.md)